# Unsupported operand types (int)+(var) error

Tags: python

```
P1Roundx=int (0)
P2Roundx=int(0)
P1Scorex=int(0)
P2Scorex=int(0)
P1Total=int(0)
P2Total=int(0)
number=int(0)
P1R1=int(0)
P2R1=int(0)
P1R2=int(0)
P2R2=int(0)

import time

Username=input("what is player 1’s username") 
Username=str(Username)
if Username == ("1"):
    print ("hello",Username,)
elif Username == ("2"):
    print ("welcome",Username,)
else:
    print("LEAVE!")
    exit()       
          # This module determines if player 1 is authenticated or if they are not. If they are not they are forced to exit the programme

Username2=input("what is player 2's username")
Username2=str(Username2)
if Username2 == ("2"):
    print ("hello,",Username2,)
elif Username2 == ("1"):
    print ("welcome",Username2,)
else:
    print("LEAVE!")
    exit()       

# This module determines if player 2 is authenticated or not and exits the programme if they are not


import random   
P1R1= random.randint(1,6)
P1R1=("Your first roll is",P1R1)
P1R2=random.randint(1,6)
P1R2=("Your second roll is",P1R2)
print("Your total is",P1R1+P1R2)
P1total=P1R1+P1R2

if P1Total % 2 == 0:
    P1Total=(P1Total)+P1R1
else:
    P1Total=(P1Total)-5+P1R1+P1R2

print("Player 1's total score is",P1Total)

import random           
P2R1= random.randint(1,6)
P2R1=("Your first roll is",P2R1)
P2R2=random.randint(1,6)
P2R2=("Your second roll is",P2R2)
print("Your total is",P2R1+P2R2)
P2total=P2R1+P2R2
if P2Total % 2 == 0:
    P2Total=(P2Total)+ P2R1+P2R2
else:
    P2Total=(P2Total)-5+P2R1

print("Player 2's total score is",P2Total)
time.sleep(6)
```

as an error, but I don't understand where the var + int is. I need help.
BTW IM NOT VERY GOOD AT THIS SNAKEY TING

Comment: The traceback should tell you where the `int` + `tuple` error originates from.

Comment: It looks like `P1R1` is a tuple. But it's impossible to be sure because you haven't included the code that defines it. If we don't have the code we can't reproduce the problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: It says line 42 which is this line. Would it help if i gave the full code

Comment: @AdamBrass We'd prefer a [mcve] rather than the full code. (But in all honesty, I think you're capable of debugging this on your own. :)  )

Comment: yes it would help

Comment: im not very good at this snakey ting. Been stuck for ages brudda

Comment: When I run this I get an UnboundLocalError because the code in your question is inconsistent about the name `P1Total`/`P1total`. So the code that is giving you the error message is not the code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code does this

```
P1R1= random.randint(1,6)
```

`P1R1` is a number between 1 and 6; let's imagine it is 4. But then the code does

```
P1R1=("Your first roll is",P1R1)
```

It appears your intent is to print this out as a message. But what it actually does is change the value of `P1R1` to the tuple `("Your first roll is",4)`. Then your code carries on as if `P1R1` still had the value `4` because it does addition on it.

If you look at the output of this line:

```
print("Your total is",P1R1+P1R2)
```

you will see that it is

```
Your total is ('Your first roll is', 4, 'Your second roll is', 1)
```

when it is clear that you are expecting

```
Your total is 5
```

It should be easy for you to see why the code goes wrong after that.

Comment: how i will btw you are a God

Answer (score 0):

hi remove the below lines which are assigning tuple to P1R1 and P2R2

```
P1R1=("Your first roll is",P1R1)
P2R2=("Your second roll is",P2R2)
```